Difference between premise and antecedent, and difference between proposition and statement?
Given the conditional statement if P then Q, is P the antecedent and Q the consequent? Can I also say P is the premise and Q is the conclusion? Is the conditional statement a proposition? Are propositions and statements the same thing? I would like to learn the rigorous definitions of logic so I appreciate any and all help/direction

See this post

"Is P the antecedent and Q the consequent?" Yes. Grammarians also sometimes use the terms protasis and apodosis respectively. It is not correct to say premise and conclusion. A conditional is a single sentence, and the antecedent and consequent are component clauses within it. Premises and conclusions are sentences in their own right that appear in an argument. An argument consists of a set of premises and a conclusion with the express or implied claim that the conclusion follows from the premises.
The term 'proposition' is used in several different ways by philosophers. Minimally, it means a declarative statement that is capable of being true or false. I listed some of the other uses in my answer to this question.
Some writers use 'statement' interchangeably with 'proposition' while others use statement to indicate an utterance of a proposition, and reserve proposition itself for the semantic content or meaning of what is uttered.

Do you have a reference from which your answer derives from? off of wiki alone, I cannot make heads or tails out of some of these definitions. If there is some dictionary of definitions with their usages I'd love to know.

These entries in the Stanford Encyclopedia should help. Conditionals. Argument. Propositions.
